# How do I prevent .NET from repairing when repairing a WiX bundle?

Tags: wix, bundle, wix3.7

I have a bundle installer created using burn that installs **.NET** as a first step:

```
<Chain>
  <!-- Applications depend on .NET 4.0 Client Profile -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40ClientWeb"/> 
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Installer1)" Visible="yes" />
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Installer2)" Visible="yes" />
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Installer3)" Visible="yes" />
  ...
```

When a user goes to repair the bundle in Add/Remove Programs, the repair process also repairs the **.NET** framework, which is very time consuming and sometimes requires a restart of the PC.  Issue with our installations are very unlikely to be with the **.NET** framework itself, so I would like to change this behavior.  I can't find the actual definition of `NetFx40ClientWeb PackageGroup`, but I assume it is marked as `permanent="true`" because it isn't uninstalled with the rest of the bundle. So why is it repaired with it?

Comment: Do you use custom managed bootstrapper application?

Comment: No, for now we are using the WiX standard BA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the WiX source and make a copy of the .NET 4 install wsx file and use that in your project, then edit NetFx40ClientWeb to remove the ExePackage/@Repair element.

Comment: Thank you!  I needed an answer, so I subscribed to the WiX mailing list to ask there as well.  This is similar to the solution I was offered from the developers, and it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: It generates a warning: warning CNDL1136: The ExePackage/@RepairCommand attribute value '' should contain '/q' when the ExePackage/@Protocol attribute is set to 'netfx4'

Comment: @Alex: See [this issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5390). Just suppress 1136.

Comment: wix source can be found here - [https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/latest](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/latest). Extract downloaded .zip or .tar.gz file and look in "\src\ext\NetFxExtension\wixlib\" directory for wxs files.